# How to have a property of a view model set the height/width for all associate child controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

Here's the scenario:  I have a flickr photo viewer, and the PhotoBrowserViewModel has a property named Image Source.  The View that is bound to my PhotoBrowserViewModel contains the following XAML.
My goal is to get the child controls to have the height/width of the ImageSource property.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="viewmodel:FlickrPhotoViewModel">
                    <controls:FlickrPhotoControl Margin="10"/> 
<!-- I want to set this control's Width/Height to {Binding PhotoSize}-->
<!-- on the same data context as ItemsControl, not as the data template.-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use relative source binding:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.PhotoSize}
```

Comment: Relative source bindings always make me feel dirty for some reason.

Comment: lol, i don't care, do it! (Alternatively you can create a reference in your resources so you can use `Source={StaticResource MyContext}` instead. You also might be able to do something with ElementName, e.g. name your window and get its DataContext)